# vim-latex on Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, vim, vim-latex

I'm a diehard vim user currently being forced to use overleaf for latex editing by various collaborators.

Since overleaf has both a vim mode and support for keybindings, I was wondering if anyone had ported vim-latex to overleaf.

I can't find anything, but surely I can't be the first vim user forced into this situation!

BTW: I'd equally well love to hear about any other latex suite for vim/emacs that has been ported to overleaf; I just want an ease of use comparable to what I currently enjoy on vim.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Maybe you should ask the Overleaf support.

Comment: They don't officially endorse these scripts. I found a couple of basic scripts on greasyfork, but nothing with anywhere near the level of functionality I'm looking for.

Comment: Or you could just use [overleaf's git integration](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/bringing-the-git-bridge-to-v2-its-here-in-beta) and and stick to your own vim setup

Comment: That's what I've been doing, but the reason I'm being forced is that overleaf offers simultaneous editing of the same file, which cannot be handled (I think) by any setup where I'm using my local vim.

Comment: A script offering bidirectional synchronization between a local text file and overleaf (or, even better, CodeMirror, so that it would also work with e.g. CoCalc) would do the trick. I do not know if it exists. If you're using Chrome, you can have a look at Atomic Chrome. It supports CodeMirror and maybe someone wrote client code for Vim. I didn't try it on Overleaf, but on CoCalc it allowed me only to edit one line at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to take a look at GhostText Plug-in (https://github.com/fregante/GhostText) for the browser (in case GhostText is compatible with your browser).

In vim one can use this Plug-in: https://github.com/pandysong/ghost-text.vim

[image: Source: ghost-text.vim github site]

Edit: I might have found this integration some place in internet, don't remember the sources to credit them. Feel free to add them in comments.

Comment: Their documentation page https://ghosttext.fregante.com/troubleshooting/ explicitly says that CodeMirror is not supported, so this can't work.

Comment: Thanks. The pandysong one worked on vim but it was a little buggy didn't give me access to the latex-suite goodness. I'm currently using [this plugin](https://github.com/raghur/vim-ghost) on neovim, and it worked with minimal pain.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be some support for Vim keybindings on Overleaf, see [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_can_I_define_custom_Vim_macros_in_a_vimrc_file_on_Overleaf%3F).

But I personally find it usually works quite OK to `git clone` an overleaf project and work on it locally. See [the documentation here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_Git_and_GitHub) and [this blog post](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/bringing-the-git-bridge-to-v2-its-here-in-beta) (already mentioned in the comments).

Answer (score 2):

I made a Vim plugin for Overleaf integration. (although it hasn't been tested extensively so there might be some bugs)

Repository link: [user202729/vim-overleaf: Edit Overleaf document from vim, with synchronization features.](https://github.com/user202729/vim-overleaf)

An animation show the plugin in action:

[image: Animation]

Comment: This is amazing, thanks, and exactly what I wanted!

Comment: One question: I eventually set up neovim with [GhostText](https://github.com/raghur/vim-ghost). Do you know if there is any important difference between your implementation and theirs? I like the recompile feature you put in so I'll definitely try yours out.